# static boost.test library and dynamic boost.test library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have a question related to BOOST.Test framework, and take the following example to illustrate my problem:
I build a TestClass library that incorporates all the test classes, and the library can be either static or dynamic. One typical function in this library is as follows:

```
__declspec(dllexport) HelloWorld()
{

        int i= 2;
        int j= 1;
            BOOST_CHECK(i == j);
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(i,j);
}
```

Then, I set up an executable program (main.cpp for example) that will invoke this library:

```
test_suite* init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{ 
    framework::master_test_suite().add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &HelloWorld ) ); 

    return 0; 
}
```

For both the TestClass library and the executable program, they need BOOST.Test library. This BOOST.Test library I built is static. Then I found:

- If the TestClass library is static, then everything goes on well.
- However, if the TestClass library is dynamic, then I received the following errors:

  unknown location(0): fatal error in "HelloWorld": std::runtime_error: can't us
  e testing tools before framework is initialized
  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: *why* are you putting your testcases in a separate DLL at all? What purpose does this serve?

Comment: @MartinBa Thanks for the comments. The reason why test cases are put in a separated DLL is because the separated DLL may contain some functions that can be used for non-test purpose.

Comment: It generally is a bad idea to mix non-test (i.e. utility or "production" code) with test code.  Keep the two separated and your life will be much, much easier.  This is simply following good [package design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_Principles), where I'm calling a library in C++ a "package".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you define the BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK:

> If you opt to link a test module with the prebuilt dynamic library,
>   this usage is called the dynamic library variant of the UTF. This
>   variant requires you to define the flag **BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK** either in
>   a makefile or before the header **boost/test/unit_test.hpp** inclusion.
>   
> [The dynamic library variant of the UTF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/usage-variants/dynamic-lib-variant.html)

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```